# How to dynamically set a property in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I am using [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) and want to set the options with a json object that is returned from ajax call. I am having some trouble setting the options property and value dynamically. Here is sample code:

```
if(data.toast){
    $.each(data.toast, function(index, element) {
    toastr.options.index = element;
    });
}
```

And data.toast is a json object that looks like this:

```
"toast":{"closeButton":true}
```

Here is what it would look like if I  hardcoded it:

```
toastr.options.closeButton = true;
```

What should I change the .index in the iterator to so that it will evaluate it as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(data.toast){
    $.each(data.toast, function(index, element) {
    toastr.options[index] = element;
    });
}
```

Doing it as `options.index` attempts to access the property of `index` not the property of the *value* of index.

The above method will fix that. It treats the object as a sort of associative array. So `toastr.options[index]` evaluates to `toastr.options["closeButton"]` which is the same as `toastr.options.closeButton`.

Comment: no, there are no associative arrays in javascript, but there is `[]` object notation